# Perceptually Corresponding Error Map

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, stitching, segmentation

Is there any better measurement of error between two images than just taking pixel value differences?

The problem I am tackling is stitching images containing "sensitive" objects, such as moving people. Here are two images I would like to blend:

[image]

[image]

I compute error map using inter-pixel differences:

[image]

The image is then considered a graph where pixels are nodes and edges are connecting neighboring pixels. Edge weights are differences between pixels taken from the error map.

Any Max-Flow/Min-Cut algorithm will find an optimal seam which goes through minimum error path (minimum cut - highlighted in red):

[image]

As you can see, the seam have successfully avoided girl's hand, but still goes through the guy's face.

The problem is in the error map which assigns too low error for his face as he just moved his head and the pixel differences of his skin are smaller than ripples on water and other less important features.

I heard about saliency map, but not sure if it is the right approach.

Comment: What result do you want to get in the blended image? Should there be two guys, or no guy, or maybe one?

Comment: The ideal result would be having higher error in the face area and hence the seam would go through the right part of the image or between the to people. I don't know about any error measurement that would have inbuilt face detection or "symmetry detection" and I am wondering if there is one.

Comment: I think an optical flow based method would work better here. Than a DSA based method.

Comment: @Naresh Thanks. I was thinking just about this recently.

Answer (score 0):

I'd mix 2 approaches:

1. Object Detection
   Train a model to detect the objects you're interested in.
   If you're really sensitive to the location, you may use segmentation.
2. [Saliency Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saliency_map)
   This will cover areas not covered in the (1) step.
   It will also add a context to the results.

You may use U-Net based methods to do both (Segmentation for (1)).